# How would I reverse this?

Tags: java, reverse

I have this code:

```
public static final BlockFace[] axis = {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.WEST};
public static final BlockFace[] radial = {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.NORTH_EAST, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.SOUTH_EAST, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.SOUTH_WEST, BlockFace.WEST, BlockFace.NORTH_WEST};

public static BlockFace yawToFace(float yaw, boolean useSubCardinalDirections) {
    if (useSubCardinalDirections) {
        return radial[Math.round(yaw / 45f) & 0x7];
    } else {
        return axis[Math.round(yaw / 90f) & 0x3];
    }
}
```

How would I go about reversing this in an efficient matter? I can think of a few brute-forcey ways, but they seem very inefficient.

So, what I have is a yawToFace() method, I want to create a faceToYaw() method.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. 
Thank you! :)

Comment: for starters, you can only get an approximate direction, since some information is being lost when rounding

Comment: @KevinL Oh, yes, of course. I only want an approximate direction.

Comment: You basically can just do the reverse of what you're doing now, i.e. `return (int)blockFace * 45f` or `return (int)blockFace * 90f`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yes, that I did think of. But I'm not sure if that will work. The '& 0x7' and '& 0x3' are doing some math calculations that I need to include when reversing it, right?

Comment: @VapidLinus nope; those are just modulo reductions by 8 and 4, respectively. Because they're powers of 2, they can be done with bitwise-and. However, they're not necessary for the reverse calculation.

Comment: @gtgaxiola Oh, okay! So, the `& 0x7` just limits it to be between 0-7? And `& 0x3` limits it to be between 0-3? So, the code _could_ work without those? Those just ensure there's no out of bounds exception? Where can I read more about that?

@DrewMcGowen Okay, thank you! I will try what you mentioned at first!

Answer (score 3):

I think storing the degrees in the BlockFace enum would be totally acceptable. Otherwise you'd  need to search through the arrays, find the matching index, and then multiply by 45 or 90.

Comment: Having the angles be the values corresponding to each `BlockFace` member means you can just do a simple typecast to get the angle. +1

Comment: That would be a good solution. However, I do not have access to BlockFace.java. I could make my own enum, however.